# Formula for conditional count of data with criteria in two different columns

Tags: count, countif

My spreadsheet records every customer encounter and what employee they see the day of the visit. There are also two columns for whether they make a same day payment or make a payment on their account balance. I need a formula that will not only count how many customers an employee sees but only counts the customers that make same day payments.

Column B has the employee's initials listed in a drop down, so I will need the formula for each employee. Column F is the column for same day payments.

If it helps, each row collects an array of information: customer last and first name, phone number, employee who helped them, same day payment, balance on account payment, and payment method. I'm trying to count how many customers are coming in and making same day payments. I need to separate it by employee for commission reasons.

I have tried:

```
=COUNTIF('1'!B:B,"BK")
```

B is the column the employee names are in and `BK` is one of the employees. This formula is counting any rows with `BK` and what I want it to do is ONLY count the rows where a "same day" payment has been made (this is column F).

Comment: You need to be more specific. Can you clarify your question a little and show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Right now I have this formula in the spreadsheet: =COUNTIF('1'!B:B,"BK"). B is the column the employee names are in and "BK" is one of the employees. This formula is counting any rows with "BK" and what I want it to do it ONLY count the rows where a "same day" payment has been made (this is column F).

Comment: If it helps, each row collects an array of info. customer last and first name, phone number, employee who helped them, same day payment, balance on account payment, and payment method. I'm trying to count how many customers are coming in and making same day payments. I need to seperate it by employee for commission reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Excel, because you need an answer for a number of employees I strongly recommend a PivotTable, therefore with your columns labelled in Row1, `Employee` for ROWS and Count of "same day" for VALUES.

However if you prefer a formula, assuming ColumnF contains `same day` to indicate the same day payments an example for employee `BK`:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,"BK",F:F,"same day")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to count for all employees (so column B not blank) where there is a value in column F (greater than 0) you could just use:

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,"<>"&"",$F:$F,">"&0)
```

Or the following will count all cells in column F that arent blank:

```
=COUNTIF($F:$F,"<>"&"")
```